# Best approch to upgrade css classes in asp and aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am working on website upgrade project (UI only ). This website has more than 5000 pages and 200 css files.

Basically In this project I have to replace old css classes with new css classes  but this is  not straight foreward. For some changes I have to modify HTML code with css class to achieve new UI look and fill.

I have identified type of changes required to migrate old page to new page. Total type of changes required are near about 15.

I am thinking about automating these 15 type of changes. Is there any tools(like html editor with regular expression support) available which will help me to achieve this functionality.

I am also thinking about developing c# based tool which will help me in achieving above changes but before that I want to know if any such kind of tool exists which will help in achieving the same.

Also if anybody worked on such kind of project then please share any other ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish this by using the find-and-replace function in your code editor.

You could also keep the existing class names and replace their properties with your new class properties. With this method, you wouldn't have to edit anything but the CSS file itself.